Using Node.JS 'require' within Nuxt framework to send Twilio SMS text
This should be relatively basic to solve, but I'm spinning my wheels on whether I am using Node's CommonJS module's 'require' function in the wrong context (i.e. Nuxt folder structure) or if I can accomplish this task in an easier fashion than suggested.
I'm essentially trying to have Twilio send an SMS text via pressing a button on my UI.
The base suggestion from Twilio for Node.JS is to include the below:
const accountSid = '[accountSid]';
const authToken = '[AuthToken]';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
client.messages
    .create({
        body: 'hello',
        from: '+18446281026',
        to: '[some_phone_num]'
    })
    .then(message => console.log(message.sid));

Using their bash script suggestion, I tested and confirmed the texting trial works, but now I need it to work within the context of my application.
I have already confirmed my API endpoint works by having it simply console.log('Working!') in the server log, but when I attempt to write my Twilio SMS "sendMsg" code I am having issues.
My folder structure in Nuxt.JS looks like this:
server/
-- api/
   -- sendMsg.ts

Where I have the below code:
export default defineEventHandler((event) =\> {
console.log(getQuery(event).msgBody)

        const accountSid = '[accountSid]';
        const authToken = '[AuthToken]';
        const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
        client.messages
            .create({
                body: getQuery(event).msgBody,
                from: '+18446281026',
                to: '[some_phone_num]'
           })
            .then((message: any) => console.log(message.sid));
      });

I'm expecting a text message on my hpone, but instead get the following error when I press the "TEST" button on my UI
Error message:
ERROR  \[nuxt\] \[request error\] \[unhandled\] \[500\] require is not defined
at Object.handler (./server/api/sendMsg.ts:7:1)  
at ./node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:1906:43  
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:105:5)  
at async ./node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:1978:19  
at async Object.callAsync (./node_modules/unctx/dist/index.mjs:72:16)  
at async Server.toNodeHandle (./node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:2270:7)

    give it a go! <---- (this was the test message, so the console.log(getQuery(event).msgBody)      
    worked!)

ERROR  \[nuxt\] \[request error\] \[unhandled\] \[500\] require is not defined
at Object.handler (./server/api/sendMsg.ts:7:1)  
at Object.handler (./node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:1904:24)  
at Object.handler (./node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:2217:34)  
at ./node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:1978:31  
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:105:5)  
at async Object.callAsync (./node_modules/unctx/dist/index.mjs:72:16)  
at async Server.toNodeHandle (./node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:2270:7)

Any help is greatly appreciated, and I'm hoping I'm missing a very small piece here.... but it's annoying!
I've tried moving the sendMsg.ts module into other folders, but it's been unsuccessful. I've also tried to do an npm install twilio and use import instead of require, but that didn't work either.

Either compile your typescript to commonjs, or use import instead of require.
